# Is magento 2 compatible with MySql 8?

Tags: magento2, database

As you all know that MySql 8.X will be released soon.

So is Magento 2 compatible with MySQL 8?

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't Supports Mysql 8 check official website , here mention " Magento application requires MySQL 5.6.x. Magento versions 2.1.2 and later are compatible with MySQL 5.7.x. Magento is also compatible with MySQL NDB Cluster 7.4.x, MariaDB 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, Percona 5.7 and other binary compatible MySQL technologies."

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 doesn't support MySQL 8 so far.

The information schema statistics is cached in MySQL 8 so there a lot of issues with auto increments and mview change logs in Magento 2.

Comment: Could you add a reference to an official source for your statements?

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Is-magento-2-compatible-with-MySql-8-x/td-p/92610

Comment: In this thread someone says that it works. I've tried it as well and my first impression is also that it works. Would be interessting to know which problems could arise.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Magento 2.4 officially supports MySQL 8

> MySQL 8.0 support. Magento 2.4.x supports MySQL 8.x. (Magento 2.4.0 was tested with MySQL 8.0.20.) Merchants are encouraged to migrate their deployments to MySQL 8.x to take advantage of its improved performance, security, and reliability.

> Although MySQL 5.7 is still supported for Magento 2.4.x, MySQL 5.6 is no longer supported. You cannot host Magento 2.4.x with a MySQL 5.6 database. See MySQL.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Magento Latest version 2.2.3 requirements:

> Database 
>   MySQL 5.6, 5.7 
>   
>   Magento is also compatible with MySQL NDB Cluster 7.4.*, MariaDB 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, Percona 5.7, and other binary-compatible MySQL technologies.

Comment: So what is exactly your answer? Is it or is it not supported? Advised (minimum) requirements does not have to explicitly exclude support for newer versions...

Comment: Not supported.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Is-magento-2-compatible-with-MySql-8-x/td-p/92610

Comment: That's not an official source, that's just another guy saying it without any good references

Comment: HERE IS OFFICIAL DOCUMENT
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html

Comment: That is only saying that it is recommended to use 5.7. It doesn't state anything about MySQL 8. Magento probably hasn't changed that page (or looked at that page) since the release of MySQL 8. I think the only valid answer to this question is a source that **_explicitly_** confirms that it works or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on CedCommerce anwer:

I installed Magento with mysql 8 and it works. The new default *caching_sha2_password* authentication plugins however introduces a breaking change as detailed in this article:

https://mjvolk.com/bug-identified-in-magento-2-2-4-installation-phase/

But you can still use the *mysql_native_password* authentication plugin with which magento will run. When you create the MySQL user for the Magento database this is the code you have to run:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```

Or if you have an existing user, change the authentication plugin with this line:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2.4.x support MySQL 8.**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes Magento 2 is compatible with MySQL 8

However for Magento's latest version MySQL 5.6 can be used
(you can also use MySQL 5.6.x)
Other compatible database for Magento 2 will be MariaDB 10 and above

Comment: Could you add a reference to an official source for your statements?