# Does Magento 2.3.5 support MySQL 8?

Tags: magento2, mysql8

Magento 2.4.0 supports MySQL 8, but **Does Magento 2.3.5 support MySQL 8?**

The Magento official doc says, You must run MySQL version 5.6 or late, which means does it support MySQL8?

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/prereq-overview.html#mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is magento 2 compatible with MySql 8?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/is-magento-2-compatible-with-mysql-8)

Comment: No, that question was for Magento 2, but I need for specific version 2.3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

> MySQL 5.7 for on-premise installations

> Magento is also compatible with, but has not been tested and is not recommended, with MySQL 5.6, MariaDB 10.1, and Percona 5.7.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

> MySQL 8.0 for on-premise installations

No

Comment: That's officially speaking. Unofficially you will have to install to find out.

Comment: I think in the below link they need to update the content.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/prereq-overview.html#mysql

Comment: I submitted a pull request - https://github.com/magento/devdocs/pull/7848 - see what happens

Comment: Thank you.. for the update..
and I'm trying to install Devdocs: https://github.com/magento/devdocs/ in Ubuntu 20.04.
Do you have any instructions how to install devdocs.

Comment: No. I just refer to the hosted version.